# I am using dot notation to access my object values that are being pushed to a list but it is not working. WHY?

Tags: vue.js, material-design

I am attempting to build a simple list using vue.js. The problem is that I am not seeing the object values that are to be rendered to the DOM using the v-for directive.

This is the code :

I am using material design for the layout

```
    <template>
      <div id = "app">

        <md-card>

          <md-card-header>

            <div class = "md-title">levi is the inner eye</div>
            <div class = "md-subhead">levi Material</div>

          </md-card-header>

          <md-card-content>

            <md-button class = "md-raised md-primary" v-on:click = "fillTable()">Fill table</md-button>
        <md-button class = "md-raised md-primary" v-on:click = "clearTable()">empty table</md-button>

            <br />

             <md-table>

              <md-table-header>

                <md-table-row>

                  <md-table-head>First name</md-table-head>
                  <md-table-head>Last name</md-table-head>
                  <md-table-head>Email</md-table-head>

                </md-table-row>

              </md-table-header>

              <md-table-body>

                <md-table-row v-for = "contact in contacts" v-bind:data = "contact" v-bind:key = "contact.firstname">

                  <md-table-cell>{{ contact.firstname }}</md-table-cell>
                  <md-table-cell>{{ contact.lastname }}</md-table-cell>
                  <md-table-cell>{{ contact.email }}</md-table-cell>

                </md-table-row>

              </md-table-body>

            </md-table>


          </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
      </div>
</template>
```

Script element

```
<script>


export default {
  name: 'app',

    data: function() {

    return {

        contacts: []

        }

    },

    methods: {

        fillTable: function() {

    this.contacts.push({firstname: 'Sebastian', lastname: 'Escheiler', email: 's.eschweiler@mail.com'});

        this.contacts.push({firstname: 'Bill', lastname: 'Smith', email: 'b.smith@mail.com'});

        this.contacts.push({firstname: 'Ann', lastname: 'Parker', email: 'a.parker@mail.com'});

        },

        clearTable: function() {

            this.contacts.splice(0, this.contacts.length);
        }
    }

}


</script>
```

Style element

```
<style>

#app {
  font-family:'Heiti SC';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Are you using [vue-material](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material)? You can't have both Vue and material design controlling the DOM without a referee. [This](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/using-material-design-with-vue-js-2-a938eac53112) may help.

Answer (score 0):

This actually appears to be working: https://codepen.io/aprouja1/pen/rwvYyV

Only thing changed in the Codepen is creating the Vue instance and selecting the #app element.

```
Vue.use(VueMaterial)

const app = new Vue( {
  name: "app",
  el:"#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      contacts: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fillTable: function() {
      this.contacts.push({
        firstname: "Sebastian",
        lastname: "Escheiler",
        email: "s.eschweiler@mail.com"
      });

      this.contacts.push({
        firstname: "Bill",
        lastname: "Smith",
        email: "b.smith@mail.com"
      });

      this.contacts.push({
        firstname: "Ann",
        lastname: "Parker",
        email: "a.parker@mail.com"
      });
    },

    clearTable: function() {
      this.contacts.splice(0, this.contacts.length);
    }
  }
});
```